# Server Sent Events NodeJS limits

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

Is there a limit how many clients a NodeJs server can handle with server sent event? As far as I understood, the server has to keep a connection to be able to send messages to the browser. How can I know how many connections be be held open without pen-testing, since it will be a shared hosting for now.

Comment: The max number of connections will be entirely dependent upon your server environment and its capabilities.  In a highly tuned and scaled, dedicated server, the limit could be hundreds of thousands.  In a shared hosting environment, you only get a piece of server resources so it's probably not a high limit (it could be as small as dozens), but unless your hosting provider describes a specific limit on the number of simultaneous sockets you are allowed, there is no way to know other than test.

Comment: How does the provider know the number of sockets? Where would he need to look?

Comment: If you're running a shared server, then you're probably (unknown to you) running in some sort of VM which manages the OS resources and can enforce limits.  This is how they guarantee that no single app hogs to much of the shared system resources.